# Stopping * been entered as user input

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a script which asks for user input and then uses it as a variable to validate a directory path exists, however when a user inputs * the validation comes back successful where it should fail.

the input is done via Read-Host, sample of the code is below.

```
$userinput = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Value"
if(Test-Path -Path "c:\$userinput\") {"Valid"} else {"not valid"}
```

Comment: `-Path` -> `-LiteralPath`

Comment: Thanks, so simple now you've mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

Just writing @PetSerAl's comment as an answer

`-path` treats * as a wild card which likely causes the success.
The solution is to use `-LiteralPath` which treats the path literally.

```
$userinput = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Value"
if(Test-Path -LiteralPath "c:\$userinput\") 
{
    "Valid"
} 
else 
{
    "not valid"
}
```